# Difficult sequence puzzle

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

What is the 25$^{th}$ term of this infinite sequence?

$$1,1,1,1,1,691,2,3617,...$$

I have tried for an hour now and I can't find any meaningful relation between the terms.

Comment: This may be useful: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C691%2C2%2C3617&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: @user222031Thanks.

Comment: This seems like an awfully cruel question without a little more direction...

Comment: @Travis. I don't think I could have solved this during a 30 year prison sentence. Ridiculous sequence.

Comment: I just typed 1,1,1,1,1,691,2,3617 into Google and the OEIS entry came up.

Comment: It seems an unlikely coincidence that the OP's name is `Rzeta` and the sequence is the numerators of rational values $\zeta(2n) \pi^{-2n}$, but there we have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the sequence of numerators of taylor series expansion of $\log(x/\sin(x))$ as can be seen in the online encyclopedia of integer sequences: [OEIS.org](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C691%2C2%2C3617&language=english&go=Search)

The next term is $43867$.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this encyclopedia.

Comment: Drilling down a bit, the 25th term in the sequence seems to be 39604576419286371856998202.